# Why was my question downvoted, with no explanatory comment?

Tags: support, down-votes

I wrote a question ([Filling out an affidavit of personal service](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/15825/filling-out-an-affidavit-of-personal-service)) which received a helpful answer.  I upvoted it and accepted it.

My question was downvoted but there was no explanatory comment.

1. Why?
2. How am I supposed to learn how to post better questions without any specific feedback?
3. What is not good about the referenced question?

Answer (score 4):

One of the "features" of Stack Exchange is that votes are anonymous, so unless a downvoter chooses to pipe up there is no way to definitively answer your first question.  ([There are other features that encourage downvoters to offer explanations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/241697).)

*Ideally* downvotes on questions are used (per the button label) to indicate, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."  *In practice* people can downvote for any reason, including that they just don't like you, are in a bad mood when they read your question, or let their cat play with the mouse while your question was on their screen.

Absent a comment, you might seek guidance regarding poorly-rated questions in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24153/the-sidebar), or here on Meta.

---

Regarding your third request, for feedback on that particular question: You're literally asking, "How do I fill out this government form?"  Personally, my first response to such a question would be, "Read the instructions, and if they're unclear contact the government agency that published it, or for which you are completing it."  (I'm actually having a hard time thinking of a question that shows less research effort.)

Comment: Have edited the question.

Comment: @aparente001 - Just amended answer.

Comment: The government body that requires this form does not provide instructions.  Looking for a definition of "ss" online yields Schutzstaffel.